# how do i include sm_11_atomic_function.h?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I can work to do a project with cuda on visual studio 2010 and windows 7. I find .cu file that needed for my project. This file have atomicExch and atomicAdd function. I compile project and i get these errors: 
            error : identifier "atomicExch" is undefined
            error : identifier "atomicAdd" is undefined

I search in web this error message. Solutions(change properties -> CUDA C/C++ ->Device -> code generation to sm_11 etc.) that I read can not solve my problem. 
Finally i right click to "atomicExch" function and click to "go to definition" and sm_11_atomic_funtion.h is seemed. I see atomicExch and atomicAdd function but this functions not active. normally code'color is black this functions is written after this row 
"**#if 
       !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 110"** .
 After this row code is not active. 
What can I do?

Comment: Please search before asking questions...

Comment: You may need to change the project properties *and/or* the file properties, to specify the code version generation.  No other changes should be needed.